# Getting spring boot Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class

Tags: list, spring-boot, exception, arraylist, classcastexception

I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class`. Not able to understand root cause of this error and how to solve it.
This is my query code:

```java
Query query3 = manager.createNativeQuery
    ("SELECT  * from trasactiondetail"
        + " WHERE orgidinsidercode = :orgid AND"
        + " shopkeeperid != :shopKeeperId "
        + " AND DATE_FORMAT(trasactiondetail.date, '%Y-%m') = :attendanceDateToRetrieve \n"  
        +" AND trasactiondetail.clientrole='Employee' GROUP BY clientmobno"
        + "  ");
query3.setParameter("attendanceDateToRetrieve", attendanceDateToRetrieve);
query3.setParameter("shopKeeperId", shopKeeperId);
query3.setParameter("orgid", orgid);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Trasactiondetail> empWhoScannedMyQRCodeButNotMyEmployee  = query3.getResultList();
```

Code to display values inside arraylist:(2 elements are present in List)

```java
for(int i=0;i<empWhoScannedMyQRCodeButNotMyEmployee.size();i++) {
  String EmployeeMob = empWhoScannedMyQRCodeButNotMyEmployee.get(i).getClientmobno();
  System.out.println("empWhoScannedMyQRCodeButNotMyEmployee  empName:  "+ empName);
}
```

Giving following error at `String EmployeeMob = empWhoScannedMyQRCodeButNotMyEmployee.get(i).getClientmobno();`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class com.sloth.generated.model.Trasactiondetail ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.sloth.generated.model.Trasactiondetail is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.sloth.generated.controller.webpage.MonthlyAttendancePageController.monthlyattendancedetails(MonthlyAttendancePageController.java:949) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `manager.createNativeQuery("SQL code")` then this method doesn't know that it should map each row from DB to `Trasactiondetail` object. So when you cast list from `getResultList()` to `List<Trasactiondetail>` - it won't work because the result list contains objects of another type (more specifically, it's `List<Object[]>` so it clearly cannot be cast to your type).

Use `manager.createNativeQuery("SQL code", Trasactiondetail.class)` instead and it should map results to this class so `getResultList` will return correct list as you expect.

I can recommend you to read more about this here: https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-native-queries/

Comment: Issue has been resolved using your solution, thank you @pawel-woroniecki.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helper you. You can also mark the answer as correct one if you want (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)